# python keyboard how to make keypresses detectable only when focused

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm writing a simple music player and I'm using keyboard module and it's on_press_key() function, but I have a problem: it detects keypresses even when the console is unfocused.

Is there a function or something to make the keypresses detectable *only* when the console is focused?

Comment: Not enough info, what libs are you using for detecting keypresses?
Sample code?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

def forward(e): .. function to forward audio ..

keyboard.on_press_key('b', forward, True)
... backward, pause, restart ...

then the read samples -> write to pyaudio loop

Comment: put code in question - it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: maybe tyou should find function `getch()` or `getchar()` which can read key pressed in console without blocking console. But `getch()`,`getchar()` is not part of module `keyboard`

Comment: do you have to run it in console? Maybe you create GUI program and then GUI gets keyboard events only when it is focused.